# Mongodb populate field from embeded documents' field

Tags: node.js, mongodb

How can i populate data of eventTypeId of eventSettings from embedded document events of mySchema

```
    mySchema : {
            events: {
                  eventSettings: [
                      eventTypeId: { type: ObjectId, ref: 'events'}
                  ]
               }
            }
```

mySchema is mongoose collection name and events is embedded document

Answer (score 0):

You can use dot notation in your `populate` call to act on embedded documents:

```
MyModel.find().populate('events.eventSettings.eventTypeId').exec(...);
```

Comment: i tried it but it gives me eventTypeId null. i also tried MyModel.find().populate('events.eventSettings.$.eventTypeId').exec(...); but it does not give me populated result.